# Deserialize object when a property in a JSON list has Dictionary<string, int>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this Class

```
public class TransactionResponse
{
     public string Serial { get; set; }
     public int Amount{ get; set; }
     public long Date { get; set; }
     public Dictionary<string, int> VatRateSum { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public int Number { get; set; }
     public bool Refund { get; set; }
     public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

}
```

And the JSON response is a list that looks like this:

```
[{      
  "Serial": "SSN-123456789",
  "Amount": 1000,
  "Date": 1659571200000,
  "VatRateSum": {
     "6": 1000
  },
  "Number": 647,
  "Type": "Normal",
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "Refund": false
},
{
  "Serial": "SSN-123456789",
  "Amount": 2000,
  "Date": 1659571200000,
  "VatRateSum": {
     "6": 1000,
     "12": 1000
  },
  "Number": 646,
  "Type": "Normal",
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "Refund": false
}]
```

When I try to Deserialize this with Newtonsoft.json like this: (resultInfo = webresponse with above JSON as result)

```
List<TransactionResponse> responseResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TransactionResponse>>(resultInfo);
```

And I always get null values in the Dictionary. Should I use some sort of JsonConverter to resolve this?

Comment: I just tried your code and everything is working properly

Comment: Learning to generate a [mcve] is critical. For example, you could have given us [this code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BSy5b8). Of course, like Serge said it's working, so you need to provide us an example of exactly what you did that isn't working, in the same format as I have done (except edit the code into your question).

Comment: Can you please let us know which version of .Net are you using and which version of Newtonsoft are you using?

Comment: C# 7.3, Netstandard 2.0.3 and Newtonsoft.json 13.0.1

Comment: Nevermind is is working and I misspelled one property in my code.